# Google Form not opening in sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a button in Google sheet to trigger container-bound script that displays form. The code logs form title and does not fail. However, I am not able to see the form inside Google sheet. Running script from editor also does not call the form.

```
function Transaction() {
    var form = FormApp.openById('1ygen0uH2SLLXvaS5kpD-mLo6wmkNA2uZQ8xVvKUisqN');
    var title = form.getTitle();
    Logger.log(title);
}
```

Comment: `openById()` simply access the form in the script. You need to serve HTML using `HtmlService` to display the form to the user inside the sheet. [The documentation guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) can help you get started.

Comment: @BrianBennett thank you